# Is Chat GPT acceptable on Mythology?

Tags: discussion

How is this permitted? If someone wanted an answer from a bot, wouldn't they just ask it themselves?

The answers aren't even good, and worse, they're often incorrect. Chat-GPT is not a fact-based machine, and so introducing it for "facts" means that we're in the business of peddling lies.

For high-rep users, you can see just how egregious it is [with this now-deleted answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/10851/are-there-any-myths-of-rulers-who-have-built-and-destroyed-their-own-domains).

Here's [another AI answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/10866/398).

Comment: Have you flagged what you suspect to be AI generated content?

Comment: Also, looking through Meta here - doesn't seem there is any policy decided on for AI generated content. Well, nothing really discussed really. However, the point is that there is no network-wide policy on AI generated content. Different stacks handle it differently and many have initiated discussion on whether it's acceptable: See [list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for the sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384923). This might be the time for this stack to discuss and reach a consensus on the matter.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I have. This question could be used for policy. Do note too that the highest answer [on a question about a complete ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide) is a hard line ban on posting answers from Chat-GPT.

Comment: It's *advocating for* a hard line ban and many users expressed agreement. However, there is no such network-wide policy. [See the staff response outlining the reasoning for not going for a blanket ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002). It's still up to individual stacks to determine their own policies.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I acknowledge that. As it's left up to the sites, I've updated this question accordingly. On other sites I participate in, including the one I moderate, it's outright banned, so I'm surprised people feel that this place of all places it is permitted.

Comment: "Permitted" seems to be a bit strong. There hasn't been a policy set yet. I assume it's because it hasn't been an issue until now. And whatever post you linked to (can't see it) is quite recent. I'd expect mods had not seen it. It's apparently now deleted, so if it was by a mod, then that means it wasn't permitted. If it was self-deleted then it's still up in the air whether the stack has taken a stance *for* or *against* AI generated content. Or even officially declaring indifference. I'm all for setting this up, though.

Comment: @VLAZ It was self-deleted, but that user [still has other answers](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/medea-in-the-dunciad/10850#10850) that come directly from Chat-GPT.